# ReactJs - Link dropdown should open separately while hovering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

I shortened the code but the logic is the same.

**The problem is:**

When I hover on "Home", the state activates for "Services" too and both of them make dropdowns open. I just want that: when I hover on "Home", "Link One" and "Link Two" appear, When I hover on "Services", "Link Three" and "Link Four" appear...
now, when I hover on "services", the state changes for "home" the same way, same time. and both of their dropdowns appear at the same time...

Have you any ideas?

Should I create fiddle or codepen example for more clarity?

```
const Header = () => {
 const [menuHoverActive, setMenuHoverActive] = useState(false)

 const handleHoverOnMouseEnter = () => {
    setMenuHoverActive(true)
 }

 const handleHoverOnMouseLeave = () => {
    setMenuHoverActive(false)
 }

   return (
    <nav className="">
                    <ul className="xl:inline-flex xl:flex-row xl:ml-auto xl:w-auto w-full xl:items-center items-start flex flex-col xl:h-auto">
                        <li className="relative">
                            <Link
                                onMouseEnter={handleHoverOnMouseEnter}
                                onMouseLeave={handleHoverOnMouseLeave}
                                className=""
                                to="/"
                            >
                                Home
                            </Link>
                            {menuHoverActive ? (
                                <ul className="flex bg-gray-700 flex-col xl:absolute xl:top-10">
                                    <li className="">
                                        <Link className="" to="/">
                                            Link One
                                        </Link>
                                    </li>
                                    <li className="">
                                        <Link className="" to="/">
                                            Link Two
                                        </Link>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            ) : (
                                ''
                            )}
                        </li>
                        <li className="relative">
                            <Link
                                onMouseEnter={handleHoverOnMouseEnter}
                                onMouseLeave={handleHoverOnMouseLeave}
                                className=""
                                to="/"
                            >
                                Services
                            </Link>
                            {menuHoverActive ? (
                                <ul className="flex bg-gray-700 flex-col xl:absolute xl:top-10">
                                    <li className="">
                                        <Link className="" to="/">
                                            Link Three
                                        </Link>
                                    </li>
                                    <li className="">
                                        <Link className="" to="/">
                                            Link Four
                                        </Link>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            ) : (
                                ''
                            )}
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
   )

  }
```

Comment: Hope this helps you, https://codesandbox.io/s/tailwind-css-and-react-forked-rq7cx?file=/src/components/Navbar.js  .. You could also try the result in the above link..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are trying to handle multiple menus hover with one Boolean variable. But that's not possible. So look at the below solution I have managed it with an object.

### Solution:

Used dyanamic variable to handle the hovering:

```
const Header = () => {
 const [menuHoverActive, setMenuHoverActive] = useState({})

 const handleHoverOnMouseEnter = (param) => {
    setMenuHoverActive({[param]: true });
 }

 const handleHoverOnMouseLeave = (param) => {
    setMenuHoverActive({[param]: false });
 }

   return (
    <nav className="">
       <ul className="xl:inline-flex xl:flex-row xl:ml-auto xl:w-auto w-full xl:items-center items-start flex flex-col xl:h-auto">
           <li className="relative">
              <Link
                  onMouseEnter={() => handleHoverOnMouseEnter('home')}
                  onMouseLeave={() => handleHoverOnMouseLeave('home')}
                  className=""
                   to="/"
               >
                  Home
               </Link>
              
               {menuHoverActive && menuHoverActive.home ? (
                  <ul className="flex bg-gray-700 flex-col xl:absolute xl:top-10">
                      <li className="">
                         <Link className="" to="/">
                            Link One
                         </Link>
                       </li>
                       <li className="">
                          <Link className="" to="/">
                             Link Two
                          </Link>
                        </li>
                   </ul>
                ) : (
                    ''
            )}
        </li>
        <li className="relative">
           <Link
              onMouseEnter={() => handleHoverOnMouseEnter('services')}
              onMouseLeave={() => handleHoverOnMouseLeave('services')}
              className=""
              to="/"
            >
              Services
           </Link>
           {menuHoverActive && menuHoverActive.services ? (
             <ul className="flex bg-gray-700 flex-col xl:absolute xl:top-10">
                <li className="">
                   <Link className="" to="/">
                      Link Three
                   </Link>
                </li>
                <li className="">
                   <Link className="" to="/">
                      Link Four
                   </Link>
                </li>
             </ul>
          ) : (
             ''
         )}
      </li>
   </ul>
</nav> )}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your state can hold only two possible values: `true` (hovering) or `false` (not hovering). You want to have (at least) three: 1. hovering on Home, 2. hovering on Services, and 3. not hovering on either.

One possible way would be to hold `"home"` or `"services"` for hovering states and, for instance, an empty string `""` for not hovering on any.